# Scala: unable to mark class method arguments as var/val

Tags: scala, immutability

```
class Time(var h: Int, val m: Int) {
  def before(val other: Time) = { //compile error due to keyword val
    (this.h < other.h) ||  (this.m < other.m)
  }
}
```

How do I mark the argument **other** in the method **before** as **var/val**? If I remove **val** before **other**, it compiles successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify the reference to `other` as it is an argument to the function.

```
def before(val other: Time) = ...
```

would be equivalent to (if it were *legal*)

```
def before(other: Time) = ...
```

If you wanted a `var`, just create it inside the function:

```
def before(other: Time) = {
  var otherVar = other
  ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of "is just equivalent", I'd say "would be equivalent if it were legal".